# Change currency format in FastReport/Delphi

Tags: delphi, formatting, fastreport

In FastReport, I want to change the format of a field that holds currency values.

Right now it uses the format `%2.2n`, which shows numbers as 1,234.50. I want to change this to 1.234,50 but can't seem to find a format in the Delphi documentation that would do this for me. Does a format with this purpose exist or do I have to build a whole new field using `FormatFloat`?

Comment: I don't know FastReport, but if it were me I would start by testing its behaviour with different locale settings first

Comment: @HughJones I need to generate reports for different countries, so changing locale settings would not be practical at all.

Comment: My suggestion was to test it to gain understanding

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not limited to the defaults you can use FormatStr e.g with `$ ###0.00` and change DecimalSeparator and ThousandSeparator as you like.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

FastReport documentation on numerical formatting is as follows :

```
for numerical formatting:
%g – number with the minimal places after the decimal point
%2.2f – number with a fixed number of places after the decimal point
%2.2n – as previous, but with thousands separator
%2.2m – monetary format, accepted by the Windows OS, dependent on the regional settings in the control panel
```

If the report is generated by the client then it's best to set it as `2.2m` but if you're generating it yourself and submitting it to the client then you'll have to go for an alternative.

Comment: But isn't `2.2m` dependent on _my_ regional settings? If I were t generate a report for a German customer and an American customer, the format would be the same for both customers, which is exactly what I want to prevent.

Comment: Yes, `2.2m` depends on where the report was generated, so if you are generating the report yourself and then submitting it to a 3rd party then you should avoid using 2.2m.

Comment: Do you have to deal with different currencies as well ? In other words if it a German customer can we assume Euro, US Dollar etc ?

Comment: @HughJones Yes, but that is handled by a script where FastReport checks the country of the customer and adjusts the currency indicator if needed. Now that I think of it I'm currently using `%2.2n`, not `%2.2m`.

Comment: I would check the help for SetThreadLocale() and GetFormatSettings().  It may be that you can cleanly switch to whichever country you need at runtime quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Before launching your report invoke `SetThreadLocale()` and `GetFormatSettings()` to the appropriate country code and allow the operating system to do the rest.